# How to connect MTP devices via USB?

Tags: usb, mount, android

How does one connect an [MTP](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32933) device to Ubuntu via USB? Many popular devices, such as all Android 4.0 phone, have only MTP or PTP as a connection option, no USB mass storage [anymore](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=24010029).

Considering the popular Samsung S3: connecting as either MTP or PTP: neither allows one to see pictures saved as default by phone camera to DCIM folder on external SD card. Similar problems with previous models (with Android 2.x) were solvable by 'usb utilities' in wireless & networking settings, but this is no longer present in Android 4.0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the "AirDroid" App from Play Store.  It allows you to use a browser based interface (on your computer) to transfer files from a Windows/Linux pc.  Since it's browser based UI, no need to install anything on the pc side.

Comment: AirDroid wants excessive permissions like contact list. For file transfer?

Comment: @GuidoKanschat may be to send file to their contact no :P

Comment: I think this is not an accepted answer.

Comment: Try Windows, it work pretty well, I means if passing by the cloud is your solution, why not using any Google Drive nor OneDrive or Owncloud, ... After all, Syncthing might be a better solution than AirDroid.

Answer (score 50):

Install [gmtp](http://gmtp.sourceforge.net/), and use it to connect to the phone or tablet :

```
sudo apt-get install gmtp
```

Comment: Awesome, still works for S5 and Kubuntu 15.10

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (as of June 2018)

Comment: "Unable to open raw device?" - on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Works for me also Ubuntu 20.04 and Files(nautilus) can also "mount" the mtp device without error. Before gmtp installed there was a /var/crash/_usr_libexec_gvfsd-mtp.1000.crash...

Comment: just installed to kubuntu 22/04, works fine

Answer (score 17):

You just install `jmtpfs` (via `sudo apt-get install jmtpfs`). After connecting your phone via USB, enable the MTP file transfer on your phone and it will show up as USB device on your computer. You can then access the whole file system (and not only the pictures, as with PTP) of your Android device.

This worked for me with (K)Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my Motorola Moto G.

Comment: Allright, working fine for my in UbuntuSTudio 16.04 x386 with SAMSUNG Galaxy J5 (Only I have to restart the PC for working)

Comment: It worked very well with my setup too - Kubuntu 16.04 & Samsung Galaxy Core Prime

Comment: Does not work with Ubuntu 18.04 and Moto G :(

Comment: It works on 18.04 but the whole computer blocks whenever I do even just some simple command like `ls android`. Why is it so slow?!

Comment: Works fine with Ubuntu 20.10 and Volla Phone on Ubuntu Touch (OTA 15).

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at this:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1643757

And this:

http://research.jacquette.com/jmtpfs-exchanging-files-between-android-devices-and-linux/

Changing from MTP to PTP (camera transfer mode) also works with nautilus, at least with the built-in memory.

Comment: Using PTP allowed me to access internal memory with Nautilus, which waht I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: heres a recentish archive.org link https://web.archive.org/web/20170226195350/http://research.jacquette.com/jmtpfs-exchanging-files-between-android-devices-and-linux/

Answer (score 7):

I have been able to do this using the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
$ mkdir phone
...Connect phone, set usb mode to MTP...
$ sudo mtpfs -o allow_other phone
...Trying to do anything with the new filesystem right now will take a minute or so, just be patient...
...Finally, you can access your phone and do whatever, then...
$ sudo umount phone
```

Here is the version this worked on:

```
$ mtpfs --version
FUSE library version: 2.8.6
fusermount version: 2.8.6
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.12
```

I haven't had perfect success with it, but I was able to get some files off of the phone. I imagine this will get better as newer software is released.

Comment: This works fine on Quantal, but not on Precise :( I think the version of libmtp is too old

Comment: @KayEss I'm on 12.04 (PP) and it worked without issue, so YMMV I guess

Comment: only approach that worked out of the box!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no GUI needed for file transfer (No One on Ubuntu is interested in making a GUI for only file transfer). And there is no need for plugins for Nautilus either. I Use Samsung Galaxy Mini (Android 2.2 ~ Froyo), and I'm doing file transfer so far by three ways, Bluetooth connection, Cable connection or using Ubuntu One app.

For cable connection you can do it easily as plug the cable, wait a while and choose mass storage mode. Access and File Transfer via Nautilus. If you want to make the phone as modem, go here: http://shiliarr95z.weebly.com/2/post/2011/07/connecting-samsung-galaxy-mini-android-phone-to-ubuntu-1104-as-modem.html.

For Bluetooth Connection, you can go here : http://shiliarr95z.weebly.com/2/post/2011/08/howto-transfer-files-via-bluetooth-laptop-to-samsung-galaxy-mini-android-phone-vice-versa.html a bit complicated but fun as well.

Using Ubuntu app is the easiest one. On the phone side,just go to Android market and install the Ubuntu one app. photo sharing runs in the background in an instant. On the Ubuntu side, just register yourself on Ubuntu One (click the envelope icon and choose Ubuntu One). And, You Have GUI on the phone side (On the Ubuntu side, you got only an OSD Message)

Answer (score 3):

For the technically noob (including me) I found just copying the file(s)/Photo(s) from the SD and pasting it to the DCIM on the phone memory will allow me to copy using the USB camera mode.  Then delete the phone file once you download to PC if you need want to clear the phone memory.

1. Go to My Files.
2. Select extSDCard
3. In this example I will select DCIM
4. Press the settings button on bottom left.
5. Select Copy.
6. Check box of files to be copied.
7. Press copy on top right.
8. Exit back to My Files.
   9   Select sdcard0
9. In this example I will select DCIM
10. Press paste in top right.
11. Exit out, select camera mode in the USB option and you should be able to transfer using simple "my computer".

Answer (score 2):

[image: Android USB]

From the home screen press Menu >  Settings >  Connect to PC > in this menu, make sure "Ask Me" is selected, if you want it to pop-up and ask you what connection type you want when you plug into the computer.

Or you can set a default action from this menu as well. You can set it to Charge Only, HTC Sync, Disk Drive, Mobile Broadband Connect.

Then Ubuntu will simply detect it as a MTP.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't transfer songs through Rhythmbox you can, like others have pointed out, transfer files using mass storage.

On my Samsung Galaxy S II you do it by going:
Applications->Settings->Connection settings->USB mass storage

Then if you plug in the USB cable it should prompt you to go to USB mass storage mode. If you say yes your phone will be available through Nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

The [git master branch of libmtp](http://libmtp.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb-index.cgi) supports the S3. If you know how to install / compile from source, you can use this until a new version is released.

I'm not on an Ubuntu machine right now, so I unfortunately can't give exact instructions regarding dependencies for compiling, etc. But it should be along the following lines:

```
git clone git://libmtp.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/libmtp/libmtp
cd libmtp

sudo apt-get install libtool libusb-dev checkinstall

./autogen.sh  (answering yes to any questions)
./configure --prefix=/usr/
make
sudo checkinstall  (answering any questions)
```

Then, you should probably make it into a .deb package, so you can install it without breaking dependencies of the programs you want to use. I'm out of my knowledge, but [Compiling source into a DEB package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package) seems to provide info.

Answer (score 2):

I have found one more application named "**Qlix**".
You can download it from ubuntu software center.

It is for **transferring files from PC to Android mobile phone**.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Transfer files between Ubuntu PC and your Android phone via wifi:

[**Xender**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender) application on your android phone allows you to transfer files between Android  and PC.

**Steps:**

- Install Xender application on your Android device from playstore.
- Create wifi hotspot on your Ubuntu pc by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/370749/202806) method and turn it on.
- Connect your phone to  pc via the created hotspot.
- Now open xender application and select "Connect PC" option on the settings menu.
- It will generate an address, (Like an ip-address).
- Put that address on your web-browser.Now you can transfer files between your phone and PC.

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I installed [Android File Transfer for Linux - MTP](https://snapcraft.io/install/android-file-transfer-linux/kubuntu) on Kubuntu and worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my Note4 was working but my S8 was not.
To fix that I installed the usual go-mtpfs and gvfs-fuse, but mainly **limesuite-udev** fixed everything.

`sudo apt install -y go-mtpfs gvfs-fuse limesuite-udev`

Of course your USB Preferences as to be set for File Transfer or MTP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from reddit, and it's working for me. You need to install these four packages:

- mtp-tools
- jmtpfs
- libudisks2-dev
- gvfs-backends

And then reboot.
In my case, I've tried to download jmtpfs from another answer here and it's not working, so after I found this solution, I installed the rest of packages (only libudisks2-dev was missing from my machine), and without rebooting my machine, thunar finally detected my phone.