# how to connect android phone with ubuntu 12.04 laptop for accessing laptop's internet connection over wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, android, internet-connection

i have an **android ics** phone and i want to use my **wired internet connection** on my laptop through wifi.

it can be done easily on windows 7 using softwares like **virtual router** or **connectify**.

is there any similar software for ubuntu. i am new to linux. i have

1.**android 4.0.4**

2.**ubuntu 12.04**

Comment: + android 4.0.4 is not rooted, and android cannot connect to the ad-hoc wireless network created in ubuntu

Comment: sir i know this. but i needed a solution for this problem. if there is a way to use ubuntu system as hotspot for android phones like we do in windows via connectify or virtual router

Comment: Try [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67663/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-with-an-android-phone?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Some mobile devices doesn't able to detect the hotspot created on ubuntu by default method.
Solution for this problem is to install *ap-hotspot* software on Ubuntu.

### **For Ubuntu 12.10,13.04,13.10**

Run these commands to install **ap-hotspot**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

Run these commands to start and stop **ap-hotspot**.

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

Run this command to configure  **ap-hotspot**

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

[image]

If it asks for WPA passphrase give a key with the minimum of 8 characters.

OR

### **For Ubuntu 12.04**

you can download the script from [**here**](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+packages?field.name_filter=ap-hotspot&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=).This script requires `Hostapd 1.0` which was available by default in `Ubuntu 12.10,13.04,13.10`.

For `Ubuntu 12.04`,add these two lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/network-manager/ppa/ubuntu precise main`
 
   `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/network-manager/ppa/ubuntu precise main`

and save the file and run the below commands in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hostapd
```

Answer (score 0):

[Software Data Cable](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lyy.softdatacable&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) does it

With it I could connect to my phone with filezilla and write files on the sd card.

Comment: buddy i need a solution to connect android phone to linux os so that i can use my computers internet on my phone.anyways thanks for the rpl