# Unable to mount Nexus 5

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I can't connect to my phone in debug mode. I am searching for about 4 hours and applied every solution already given in other questions. Following is the output of `mtp-detect` command

```
allaudin@geek:~$ mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.10

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee2) is a Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP+ADB).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung): Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP+ADB) (18d1:4ee2) @ bus 1, dev 17
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
```

Anyone with solution?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/854332/how-to-connect-android-7-1-to-ubuntu-linux-with-usb

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. I can actually transfer files to my phone. But I can not connect it in Debug mode for running apps from Android Studio.