# Android phone keeps remounting itself

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, phone, mtp

I have a problem when copying pictures and videos from my android phone, the android phone keeps **remounting** itself and because of that the **copying process halts** and I can't copy the files that I want to copy.

I use **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (kernel version: 4.2.0)**, I had other problems with other phones when copying files like some files not copying. I am also wondering if I upgrade to a newer kernel or just update the whole distro to a newer version (which would also update the kernel version), will problems with the MTP mounting and stuff like this be fixed? **Do you know any temporary fix I can do so the phone doesn't automatically remount itself every time when I try to copy somehting?**

Comment: I've found this.....

https://askubuntu.com/questions/854332/how-to-connect-android-7-1-to-ubuntu-linux-with-usb

It may help.

Comment: Ok, I used another usb port and it stopped remounting, maybe that was the problem, although I remember having issues on Linux/Ubuntu with that port too, I assume that the problem is something from the kernel and not from the usb ports, since I recall that it works well on Windows (and maybe it can be fixed with a distro update in the future), thanks for the information you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Android File Transfer for Linux will always work!  it just works!

see answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1111802/183131