# Ubuntu doesn't recognize my Galaxy 9 phone

Tags: drivers

It was working fine a few days ago then all of a sudden. Nothing.I'll plug it in phone says allow access, yes and it will show SD card and Phone but try open SD card and I get libmtp error can not get object handles.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Askubuntu! Please edit your question and include the error so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Always mention what version of ubuntu ... especially on anything IO related

Comment: 18.04 is current version.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but with Samsung S6 Edge.  I used Android File Transfer for linux and it worked!  Worked fantastically actually!  In a nutshell,... "It just works!"

You will have to download and build it from Github:
https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux

Just to add to the limited instructions on the "how to build page" on Github for the less technical, also google's your friend if the instructions underneath aren't clear enough;

1. `~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libqt4-dev
   ninja-build libfuse-dev libreadline-dev`
2. Find a path in your pc where you want to keep the source code for
   AFTL
3. Clone AFTL to that location then as the instructions on the github page says...
4. `~$ mkdir build`
5. `~$ cd build`
6. `~$ cmake ..`
7. A little bit of a modification here to build things much faster!
   `~$ make -j<number of cores you have>`.  So in my case with an i7
   cpu it s `~$ make -j8`
8. `~$ cd qt`
9. `~$ ./android-file-transfer`
10. In many computers it will give you some pop-up error saying that
     there is already some other process or rather using MTP or busy or
     something similar.  It will give you the option to kill them by
     pressing "abort". **DO THAT!** It will kill those useless non-function
     processes.  Then you will get AFTL running showing you all the
     folders on your phone.
11. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This is a big fat band-aid NOT a solution ... install an `FTP Server app` on your android ... I tend to use the one from "The Olive Tree" ... launch that app and enable the ftp server ... go to ubuntu open up Files (file manager) and hit `+ Locations` on left column then enter the ftp address as shown on your phone similar to

```
ftp://192.168.1.102:2221   # <-- your IP may be different
```

now you are connected and can transfer files between phone <--> ubuntu

Android 7 <--> ubuntu {16.04...19.04}

I personally find ubuntu a very nice distro however its Android connectivity is extremely poor and has been since the beginning may years ago ... I tend to use pre-release editions so when things like this fail I chalk it up to me compiling/installing too many rogue repos ... hence this work around as I really hope someone pipes in with a real solution