# Android 9 phone on Ubuntu 18.10 not showing up

Tags: usb, android, 18.10, phone

I have an Android 9 phone (Google Pixel XL) which does not show up when I connect it to my laptop via USB. I have Ubuntu 18.10.

I have enabled developer options and USB debugging. When I connect my phone, I can choose "File Transfer" from the phone, but the phone still doesn't show up on Ubuntu.

I was able to authorize the computer from the phone, and the phone shows up when I do `adb devices`, but I still don't see the phone in my file manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my answer on this link: https://askubuntu.com/a/1111802/183131

But basically Android File Transfer for Linux should do the trick.