# Connecting Google Pixel 2 to Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, android

I just bought a Google Pixel 2 (Android 8.0.0) and tried to connect it to my PC (Ubuntu 16.04).

I tried in developer mode and changed to USB connection setting as MTP (Media Transfer Protocol), however, when the two devices connected to each other, it only showed that Google Pixel 2 is charging but never got recognised by Ubuntu.

Any suggestions on how can I connect Pixel to my PC and transfer files between the two devices. BTW, I connect Pixel and my PC using USB c cable that comes with the phone and I tried using USB 2.0 adaptor and a third party USB 2.0 cable, it does not even show its charging.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this as an answer because Ask Ubuntu won't let me post it as a comment.

I have been able to connect my Pixel 2 to Ubuntu 16.04 by installing jmtpfs, as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/854936/297597. Once I enable MTP in the developer settings, plugging in the phone opens up a new Nautilus window with the phone contents. I used a USB 1.0 port. The frustrating part was that the connection was very unstable and kept resetting, but I think it could be due to my old USB port.