# How to connect a Google Pixel 2 phone to Ubuntu 20.04 (or later)

Tags: usb, android, transfer

What is the procedure to connect a Google Pixel 2 (or maybe higher) phone to a PC (host, not VM) running Ubuntu 20.04 or later?

Comment: Sorry, I vote for closing this question too, but move it into Answer of the referenced question "how do I connect my Pixel 2"

Answer (score 0):

For these instructions you don't need to install either mtp-tools or jmtpfs.

1. See Sullivan's answer to [How to connect Android 7.1 to Ubuntu Linux with USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854332/how-to-connect-android-7-1-to-ubuntu-linux-with-usb/854936#854936)  to understand this, but do not follow its instructions and use the below steps (Step 1 and Step 2) instead.
2. (Step 1): On the Pixel 2 phone:
   (IMPORTANT: do NOT activate *USB tethering*, or else Ubuntu will not recognize the phone: USB tethering MUST BE OFF).

   a. Connect your phone via USB to the computer.
   b. Swipe down from the top of the phone screen.
   c. Go to *USB Preferences* and activate the uppermost option *File transfer* (and not even *USB tethering*, as mentioned above!)

   [image]
3. (Step 2): On the Ubuntu computer:
   (Although already showing the "Pixel 2" phone, but with an empty folder, previously)

   a. Exit your file browser (nautilus).
   b. (Re-)Start your file browser and be surprised to see the now displayed *Pixel 2* -> *Internal Storage*.
   c. On the computer navigate to *Pixel 2* -> *Internal Storage* -> *DCIM* -> *Camera* and see your recorded photographs there. You now can copy the photographs and paste them to a folder on your computer.