# Android M phones don't display all content in Thunar via MTP

Tags: usb, xubuntu, android, mtp, thunar

After initially not recognising MTP at all ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146529/how-to-connect-mtp-devices-via-usb)) I have an issue with both my Nexus 5 and my new Nexus 5x whereby some - *but not all* - DCIM (camera) and Music folder content shows up in Thunar. I can see the discrepancy on the phone itself or via AirDroid

Thunar view of MTP connected phone on left, AirDroid view of same on right:

[image: Thunar view of MTP connected phone] [image: AirDroid view of MTP connected phone]

As far as I recall, all files were added using AirDroid, but at different times. The same happens with camera images. Possibly-helpfully, <=5 day old pictures were listed in Thunar, >=6 day old pictures weren't. Photos taken on same phone in same timezone with no other obvious changes. This is NOT true for the music: Elephant (White Stripes; present in Thunar) was added most recently but before that was Deep House (absent Thunar) and before that The National (present Thunar). No obvious pattern to the present/absent folders.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Edit: versions of stuff: xubuntu 15.10 Thunar 1.6.10

Comment: What Ubuntu release?

Comment: Sounds likely to be a bug in libmtp.

Comment: apologies, versions added: xubuntu 15.10 Thunar 1.6.10 libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmtp-common 1.1.9-3ubuntu1

Comment: Trying to install libmtp 1.1.11 now but getting "libusb not found! (missing -dev/-devel package?)" even though I have libusb-1.0-0 2:1.0.19-1 installed. I'm worried about going further & installing 1.0.20 (latest) in case it makes things worse.

Comment: ugh. Down the linux rabbit hole. Tried installing libusb, hits "configure: error: "udev support requested but libudev not installed"". Software center shows libudev1 225-1ubuntu9 installed.

Comment: Support request left with libmtp team asking them whether they think it's likely that libmtp is to blame https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/support-requests/206/

Comment: "libusb not found! (missing -dev/-devel package?)"  Try `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev`

Answer (score 1):

According to [go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs)

> Go-mtpfs is a simple FUSE filesystem for mounting Android devices as a MTP device.
>
> It will expose all storage areas of a device in the mount, and only reads file metadata as needed, making it mount quickly. It uses Android extensions to read/write partial data, so manipulating large files requires no extra space in /tmp.
>
> It has been tested on various flagship devices (Galaxy Nexus, Xoom, Nexus 7). As of Jan. 2013, it uses a pure Go implementation of MTP, which is based on libusb.

install the Go compiler suite; e.g. on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install golang-go
Install libmtp header files
sudo apt-get install libusb1-devel
```

Then run

```
mkdir /tmp/go
export GOPATH=/tmp/go
go get github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs
```

`/tmp/go/bin/go-mtpfs` will then contain the program binary.

You may need some tweaking to get libusb to compile. See the comment near the top of usb/usb.go, ie.

```
 # edit to suit libusb installation:
 vi /tmp/go/src/github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs/usb/usb.go
 go install github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs
```

A 32 and 64-bit linux x86 binaries are at

[go-mtpfs](http://hanwen.home.xs4all.nl/public/software/go-mtpfs/)

**USAGE**

```
mkdir /tmp/go
GOPATH=/tmp/go go get github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs
sudo mv /tmp/go/bin/go-mtpfs /usr/bin/
mkdir ~/Android
```

to mount device:

```
go-mtpfs ~/Android
```

Comment: Thanks. Some notes (not intended to be snarky, but for other users' ease): "Install libmtp header files" shouldn't be formatted as code. I think it should be "sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev" as it's "Unable to locate package libusb1-devel".  Having done this, I'm not having any luck getting it to work. Thanks for your answer, I'll have another try with it tomorrow.