# Unable to connect to MTP device

Tags: usb, android, mtp, 18.10

I'm unable to connect to my Redmi Note 5 Pro, I'm on MIUI 10. However I'm able to connect to other devices (One Plus 3T).
I tried installing `gmtp` [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/160626/786263), also tried to change the cable. I also tried to install `libmtp` from [this repo](https://github.com/mmalecki/libmtp), but nothing works.

I'm getting this error when I try to access my device :

> Unable to access "SDM636 MTP SN:E5BA4F65"

PS: I'm able to access the device from Windows 10 in the same laptop, but not in Ubuntu 18.10.

I'm unable to access my device through android studio too.
Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Comment: I have following two ways to answer. Choose whatever you like. 1.[How to connect Android device using MTP Ubuntu - Youtube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/IqVXbaL-kQg) 2.[answer to similar question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1095599/870751) Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install `go-mtpfs` with

```
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs
```

Create a directory:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Redmi5
```

set the ownership of this directory with

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/Redmi5
```

Then you can mount/unmount this directory with:

Mount:

```
go-mtpfs /media/Redmi5 &
```

Unmount:

```
fusermount -u /media/Redmi5
```

You will have to do this every time you want to mount it.
File transfers are extremely slow.

This is the best solution I have found so far.