# Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish not connecting to my Android phone. Showing ERROR: Unable to access & couldn't find matching udev device. What to do?

Tags: android, udev, 18.10, mtp, cuttlefish

Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish is not connecting to my Android phone. It shows the error:

> #### Unable to access "SDM636 MTP SN:E48333B7"
>
> Couldn't find matching udev device.

[image: Error message]

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

[How to connect Android device using MTP Ubuntu- Youtube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/IqVXbaL-kQg)

Connect an Android device using MTP in Ubuntu.

You need to follow following steps because ubuntu doesn't show your mtp devices (security reasons). 
Open a terminal and type commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9 

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

[Remove # from in front of last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svJYN.png)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fuse.conf
```

[connect your phone to your pc (unlocked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVKnr.jpg)

```
$ lsusb
```

[open new terminal and type the following command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1xgJ.png)

```
$ sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/69-mtp.rules
```

copy and paste below lines and replace Device with your phone name and the addresses as shown in image below.

[replace the addresses as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0f2k.png)

```
# Device 
ATTR{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTR{idProduct}=="YYYY", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

type the following command

```
$ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

[Replace the addresses as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEJEU.png)

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTR{idProduct}=="YYYY", MODE=”0666" 

$ sudo service udev restart 

$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Not working on my HTC U12+

Comment: use this link https://youtu.be/IqVXbaL-kQg

Comment: Very sad it didn't work for me.