# How to convert .tar.gz etc to .deb format using ubucompilator/checkinstall?

Tags: deb, install-from-source, conversion, checkinstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling source into a DEB package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package)

I have some tarballs I want to convert into Debian packages. I usually use `gdebi` to install .debs but tarballs are difficult for me to use. How can I use `checkinstall` or `ubucompilator` to make these .deb files?

Comment: If you follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall what steps doesn't work for you, and for which specific piece of software?

Comment: i use ubuntu 12.10(64 bit) on my windows dual booted toshiba p755-s5215 laptop

i'm gettin this msg after
sudo aptitude install checkinstall   
sudo checkinstall 

 The package documentation directory ./doc-pak does not exist. 
Should I create a default set of package docs?  [y]: y

Preparing package documentation...OK

*** No known documentation files were found. The new package 
*** won't include a documentation directory.

Please write a description for the package.
End your description with an empty line or EOF.

Comment: for java: `make-jpkg` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

From http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/249-how-to-use-checkinstall-to-create-packages-from-sources/:

Install `checkinstall` using apt (or your favourite package installer):

```
sudo apt install checkinstall
```

Extract the tarball into a directory. In this case, it is `/tmp/program_example`. Open `terminal` and cd into it with:

```
sudo -i

cd /tmp/program_example
```

Now, run:

```
make
```

and then

```
checkinstall -D --pakdir=/home/youruser/packages/
```

which will make a deb package in `/home/youruser/packages`, and install it. You can then reuse it and give it to others. Do not use this to make a package for a PPA or package server. These must be made and tuned manually.

When it prompts you to give a description, just describe the package and then press Enter a few times to finish it.

Comment: "Extract the tarball into a directory. In this case, it is /tmp/program_example"
can u give me a example

Comment: @abh-kirrack Just use archive manager into a directory. Remember the name of that directory. Or `cd` to the file and `tar xvzf program.tar.gz` then `cd` to the folder with the same name as the tarball.

Comment: after the last step i'm getting this msg
***no rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
**** Installation failed. Aborting package creation.