# How to create a .deb package from compiled source files?

Tags: 12.10, package-management, ppa, packaging, mono

Question:

Mono 3.0 is out, but I found no ppa from where I could install it.

There is this one:
https://launchpad.net/~directhex/+ppa-packages

but it's mono 2.10.8.1-5.

I'm playing with ASP.NET MVC4, which is why I need the 3.0 release.

Now I can compile & install mono 3.0 myself. 
How I do it, I tutorialized here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591370

My problem now is, for every new ubuntu installation I have/want to make (server, laptop, desktop, renewed installation when HD breakes) I need to go through this lengthy procedure again.

So I want to compile it once, and then upload it to a PPA, so that I (and everybody else) don't need to install it from source again.

Now the question:
The entire build process needs configure run with options, post-configure makefile fixes, post-configure sourcecode fixes, etc.

Is there an easy way I can create .deb packages from the already compiled files ?

So that in the installation script, I only need to write several times:

```
cd package_directory_1/
make install
cd package_directory_2/
make install
cd package_directory_3/
make install
```

etc.

?

Comment: For personal use , you can use checkinstall, But it is not enough for ppa

Comment: Packaging is a job on its own. It's not something you just do by running a simple set of commands. `dh*` scripts to aid you have *a lot of* heuristics, but will not automate all for you. I suggest you to start by looking at current packages (`dget http://some-ppa/thepackage.dsc`) and the [Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide). The good news is that GNU Autotools powered sources are fairly easy to package (at least for personal use, not having to meet the high standards in Debian/Ubuntu).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling source into a DEB package](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

checkinstall, as per tip from Tachyons

```
apt-get install checkinstall 

checkinstall -D make install
```

See here for further information:
http://www.falkotimme.com/howtos/checkinstall/

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
make package
```

It will not install anything but create a package.

JM

Comment: Error "make: *** No rule to make target 'package'. Stop."