# How to build a deb package of a project on github?

Tags: 12.04, debian, github

I want to make a deb package of a project - https://github.com/manojgudi/sandhi 
Is there any way of doing this without first installing the software on my system? If no then after installing it on my system and getting it working what steps to follow now to create a deb package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a .deb package from compiled source files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240027/how-to-create-a-deb-package-from-compiled-source-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `checkinstall`, it builds a package from sources.

Read up on it here: https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall