# Software installation, no package after succefull sudo make install

Tags: command-line, software-installation, make, cmake

I think this is general question about software installation in Ubuntu (20.04) and I don't understand some obvious things.

I need: "CMake 3.17 or higher is required". In repos and software app versions are older, so the only way I have found is to download and install it from the developers site. I succesfuly run

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

but there are still no package cmake in the system (like, after sudo apt-get install cmake). All the guides on packages installation stop at this step and don't mention what to do after you pass sudo make install. The repeat of this command is says that everythin is up to date.

Answer (score 4):

The *configure–make–make install* procedure does not create a Debian package (`*.deb`) which can be managed by APT.

The result of the *configure–make–make install* procedure are files installed to `/usr/local`. When you call `which cmake` on your machine now, you should get `/usr/local/bin/cmake` as opposed to `/usr/bin/cmake` [installed by APT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8658/54675). And if you run `cmake --version` (with the default contents of the `PATH` environment variable), you should get the version number of your self-compiled version. If your version is working correctly, you can even uninstall the packaged version (`apt remove`) and continue using your version.

If you want to create a Debian package, there are [various guides](https://askubuntu.com/q/1345/250300), you can also check [How to create a .deb package from compiled source files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240027/how-to-create-a-deb-package-from-compiled-source-files) for an automated solution.