# Packaging precompiled program: file list not found

Tags: packaging, deb

I'm trying to package an already compiled set of binaries including doc, header files, usage examples, etc...

The installation instruction of the original binaries recommends to just copy all files to a directory below `/usr`

So I've made the following `debian/install`:

```
bin/* /usr/tigcc/bin
doc/* /usr/tigcc/doc
examples/* /usr/tigcc/examples
include/* /usr/tigcc/include
lib/* /usr/tigcc/lib
projects/* /usr/tigcc/projects
```

Now I'm using `debuild -uc -us -sa` to generate the .deb file. I'm confronted with this error:

```
 dpkg-genchanges -sa >../tigcc_0.95-0ubuntu2_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: Fehler: Dateienliste-Datei kann nicht gelesen werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
#translation: error: couldn't read file list file: File or directory not found
```

Why am I getting this error? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: debian/rules

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
        dh $@
```

(default from some packaging guide)

**Edit**: `ls -lhR debian`

```
debian:
total 36K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian  147 Feb 22 15:45 changelog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian    2 Feb 21 23:46 compat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian  454 Feb 23 12:43 control
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian 1.2K Feb 23 12:19 copyright
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian  148 Feb 26 21:39 install
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian  102 Feb 23 12:13 postinst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian   79 Feb 23 12:13 preinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sebastian sebastian   85 Feb 26 21:39 rules
drwxrwxr-x 2 sebastian sebastian 4.0K Feb 21 23:11 source

debian/source:
total 4.0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastian sebastian 12 Feb 21 23:11 format
```

---

**EDIT**: I tried to create a file `debian/files`, just because I somehow thought it might help. The error vanished, but `debuild` just said "nothing to build" a few times and finished without generating a package at all.

---

**Edit**: Following the request of one of the people trying to help me, I'm now supplying links to the files used.

The original binaries can be found [here](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/linux/tigcc_bin.tar.bz2), the stuff below `debian` [here](https://db.tt/clf5pRRV).

**NOTE**: These link point directly to tar archives.

Comment: How did you obtain the compiled files? Perhaps you want this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package .

Comment: I've downloaded the binaries from TIGCC's website and asked the developers what should be installed where

Comment: you need a `debian/rules` file. Do you have that?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -lhR debian`.

Comment: What is in `debian/compat` exactly?

Comment: It's only content is the number `9`

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `debian/rules` file?

Comment: It's already there

Answer (score 1):

Remove the preceding `/` character in the `/usr/tigcc/…` statements in the install file.

Also, you should either make that be `opt/tigcc/…` or remove the `tigcc` bit and install them properly integrated into the FHS standard paths, depending on what the binaries are compiled to expect exactly.

Also, add `--fail-missing` as an argument to dh, like:

```
%:
    dh $@ --fail-missing
```

This will cause the build to fail when installed files are not included in the package.

Comment: So it's only `usr/tigcc/bin` etc. Instead of `/usr...`?

Comment: removing the leading `/`s didn't have an effect. Still the same `error: cannot read files list file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will suggest a hackish workaround. Make a backup, then get rid of `install`, `postinstall`, `preinstall`. Then in `rules` add the following at the end of the file:

```
override_dh_auto_install:
dh_auto_install
    mkdir debian/packagename
    mv bin/* debian/packagename/usr/tigcc/bin
    mv doc/* debian/packagename/usr/tigcc/doc
    mv examples/* debian/packagename/usr/tigcc/examples
    mv include/* debian/packagename/usr/tigcc/include
    mv lib/* debian/packagename/usr/tigcc/lib
    mv projects/* debian/packagename/usr/tigcc/projects
```

Then make a copy of the entire dir containing the `debian` folder and the rest of the pre-compiled binaries, and on that try to *build binaries* by using `debuild -b -us -uc`. I suspect that this should work, but make sure that all the paths are correct and that all file move operations proceed as expected.

---

**UPDATE**:

I played with the linked binaries and `debian` dir. I had to adjust the file names, the folder structure and the `control` and `rules` directives.

- [binary archive](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08980821866728158702)
- [debian dir](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=91344622044608959650)
- [resulting .deb](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55250275923686421428)

To reproduce the `.deb`, you need to unpack the binary archive, unpack the debian dir within the extracted `tigcc` dir, then run `debuild -b -us -uc` from within the `debian` folder. Put both archives in a temporary folder, then:

```
bzip2 -d -c "tigcc-0.95_orig.tar.bz2" | tar -xf - 
cd tigcc/
tar -zxf  "../tigcc-debian.tar.gz"
cd debian/
debuild -b -us -uc
ls -l ../../*deb
```

Unless you have some missing dependencies, I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: It shows the same error...

Comment: OK, then you need to provide a link to the pre-compiled binaries, and to the tar.gz of the `debian` dir. Otherwise it's a lot of guesswork, and perhaps something is simply to placed in the correct dir.

Comment: @the_Seppi I've now posted the `.deb` and the archives with the necessary folder/file structure to make it work. Inspect at leisure and feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Followed all your instructions, still `dpkg-genchanges: error: cannot read files list file: No such file or directory`

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: I read the manpage of the error-producing command, and it says it needs the `debian/files`. Should this file be created by `debuild` or do I have to do so manually?

Comment: I'm no expert, but as far as I can see there is no need for `debian/files` in the original `debian` dir. I maintain various packages, and there is no such file in them. This file does appear though when you try to build the binaries using `debuild -b -us -uc`. In any case, the `.deb` package creation works just fine here under 12.04, as indicated in the answer.