# xz-utils 5.2.1 on trusty: how to compile and re-package? Or ppa available?

Tags: apt, software-installation, packaging

I want to compile and use a newer version of xz-utils, in this case version 5.2 as well as create deb-packages to be distributed on different ubuntu (14.04) machines. The recent changes to xz were significant, including multi-threaded compressing(!). I could not find a ppa of the recent 5.2.1 version of xz-utils (including liblzma, etc.) so i decided to try to create the package myself.

After downloading the source code, there are a lot of files different to the original sourcecode; most notably the "patches" folder. Unfortunately a full list of ubuntu-related changes is nowhere to be found, so I can try and recompile this ubuntu-style.

My questions are:

1. How to compile xz-utils including liblzma so it can be used as a
   system-replacement on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty, replacing the xz (XZ
   Utils) 5.1.0alpha?
2. How to package the deb files to be installed on other machines
   running Ubuntu 14.04?

thanks!

Comment: Run `gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AFE11347` and then check again..

Comment: ok thanks, this did the trick for the dsc file. i am still wondering how to proceed from here regarding the patches and the specifics for debian/ubuntu...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling source into a DEB package](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package)

Comment: i rephrased the question so it is more clear what i am asking regarding xz-utils and liblzma