# WINE not properly uninstalling

Tags: apt, wine, uninstall

So I recently updated to WINE version 1.9.6 from version 1.6.2 (from software manager).  The new version was not working, so I decided to uninstall it, and reinstall the old version, but the new version 1.9.6 seems to not be uninstalling.  I've tried

`sudo wine uninstall wine`

`sudo apt-get purge wine`

`sudo apt-get remove --purge wine`

and all of these options with wine*, wine-1.9, and wine-1.9.6 as opposed to simply wine.  Nevertheless, when I check the version of wine, it shows up as 1.9.6.

Reinstalling the old version from the software manager doesn't seem to help either.  What else can I do to get rid of this version?

edit: 
`which wine` shows /usr/local/bin/wine

Comment: Can you include the output of `which wine` so we know where it's installed?

Comment: According to the current Ubuntu wine package here http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/wine1.6/filelist the official packages only install in /usr/bin and not /usr/local/bin   Did you install this using a package from an unofficial source or by manually compiling it?

Comment: I had installed it by compiling the download from the wine website.  I think I finally got rid of it by going into /usr/local/bin and executing `sudo rm wine*`

Comment: That's one way of doing it, but it will leave behind alot of files also.  If you installed it with a `make install` then you should also be able to uninstall it with `make uninstall`

Answer (score 0):

From the additional information and comments, it appears that you have installed a version of wine by downloading and running a compilation process such as:

```
$ make
$ make install
```

This makes certain assumptions, such as that the default bin directory is **/usr/local/bin** instead of Ubuntu's **/usr/bin** which means that you could have multiple installations of the same application and can create all sorts of headaches.

**If you end up in this position:**

The cleanest way to remove an application installed in this way is to run the application's own uninstall process, e.g.:

```
$ make uninstall
```

or (more rarely)

```
$ make remove
```

Failing that, you may have to look at the Makefile to find out where all the files are and manually `rm` them.

**To avoid this happening again:**

This is why it's recommended, even with outside applications, that you put them into a debian package, or use a tool like **[checkinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package)**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1439989 also mentions that, if all else fails, `make -n install` lets you see what changes `make install` makes.