# How to create virtualbox.deb file after compililg Virtualbox OSE source package

Tags: virtualbox, compiling, deb

**I just want to manually create virtual box.deb** file after successfully compiling the source code (**Virtualbox-5.0.16.tar.bz2**). I have done hardend build for compiling virtualbox and followed this link on my Ubuntu desktop  [virtulbox build instructions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux%20build%20instructions)

Comment: I think [this is what you are looking for](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should learn about packaging. Almost never would a wise person "build from source" and then try to wrestle that  into a package. Instead, one would fiddle around with files in the source directory (the debian directory) and build a package with dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot.  If none of that makes sense, you seriously need to learn about packaging.

One good avenue is to run "apt-get source your-package-name-here" and it will pull down the source and packaging so you can see how real packages are actually made.

Now, suppose you ignore that whole speech. I'm trying to save you from yourself. There is a way to fake a package build by monitoring the effect of "make install" that grabs the files and makes them into a pseudo package.  This  is called "checkinstall", but if you do it, you will be ridiculed by the  much more knowledgeable  people who properly build packages. I'm not teasing. If you admit to any reasonable Debian or Ubuntu  user that you use check install, you can become a laughingstock.

https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

When your friends brand you with a name like "lazy Linux user who refused to learn the proper way to do anything", you won't be able to say I did  not warn you.

But I did this  once when the packaging for one Debian project was put together in such a ridiculous way that rebuilding their packages--even if it did work--resulted in an awful spew.

Answer (score 0):

Run "debuild -us -uc" in the main folder.  You may also need to install some additional packages to get debuild to work, but it should tell you what it's missing.