# How to generate deb files with source code without makefile

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb, debian

I've known that we could use `checkinstall` to generate deb files from source code, which allows us to execute `apt install` to install them into my Ubuntu system. Here is how `checkinstall` works: [Compiling source into a DEB package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package)

In a word, `checkinstall` works based on the `Makefile`.

However, as we know, there are some components, such as boost, which doesn't contain any `Makefile`, here is the way to compile the boost:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2
```

So I simply want to know if it is possible to generate deb files for boost with its source code and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should read from Debian Wiki .
https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

It is very known the GNU autotools, but it is not for generating .deb.